# How to locate the Dynamic WebElement using WebDriver

Tags: java, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

**Automation Specification- Java based WebDriver**

Hi
i'm working on a webdriver automation(Java code) to automate bus booking.
 Here is my scenario....

> (1)give Departure & Destination - **DONE**
>   (2) Pick the Date - **DONE**
>   (3)Search Bus -**DONE**
>   (4)View Seats & Select- **I Struck here**

Now as a search result, i got a list of buses with the option to view the seats.
the list of buses are shown in a **dynamic-DataTable** which contains an image called '*view seat*' in each row. A click on the *viewseat-image* will give me the seat-layout where i can select the *seats*. found the viewseat-images are having **different id's** & the **same class name**. Now i need to locate and click on the viewseat-image whichever i want, using its id. 
**But the situation is**
* the data table is dynamic, So the id's keep changing which doesn't allow me to locate it by a static id.
* id is the only unique thing in that coding to differentiate the viewseat-image from another. so i can locate it only if i get the id correct.

Now my idea is to, *get the runtime id's of all viewseat-images, using the unique class name and store in variables and use the id's to locate the element.* 
So let me know if there any possibility to get the id's of all images in that data table, using the class name.

Comment: Have you tried using a different selector instead of the ID for the seats? Xpath, CSS, etc.
If you could provide a html code snippet as part of your question it will be easier to assist you.

Comment: I tried to. but i couldn only find ID & class name in the HTML. here is the HTML code for a viewseat-image which is mentioned above.. `<a id="100001610410140976/2013-11-07" class="pop-up viewSeatsButtonStyle" href="javascript:void(0);">View seats</a>`

Comment: There are other selectors than just the ID, name, classname etc. Sometimes you need to use the 'uglier' methods of xpath or css. If you could add in a html snippet of a section of the table rather than just of that anchor I can try and point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks @MarkRowlands. i too looked for classname,name,cssSelector. but couln't find. And our devs are using hte DataTable instead of Grid View to show this list.So HTML snippet of the Table will be too hard for you if give since it contains a hell outa css tags. so i give you the overview of the table. Table contains Columns like TRAVELS NAME, DEP TIME, ARRIV TIME, PRICE,then finally VIEWSEAT image.

Comment: so i give you the snippet for travel operator & viewSeat alone. `<a id="103838910410032127" class="cancel cancelonwards" name="2013-11-07" href="#" style="color:#4A5892;font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:200;">Canc.Policy</a>

<a id="103838910410032127/2013-11-07" class="pop-up viewSeatsButtonStyle" href="javascript:void(0);">View seats</a>`

Comment: Ok lets rewind because, unfortunately, I'm become confused by what you've said. No matter. Your original question was how to find the seats and click on them. If I've followed your description properly, the seat elements should follow on from the `'View seats'` element.
S0 - `Webdriver element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("View seats")); List<WebElement> seats = element.findElements(By.xpath("//the-xpath-tag-for-each-seat"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute path and take the location of the seat which will reduce your efforts, to take the absolute path you can install a plug-in in firefox called "firepath", after installtion you will have an option for selecting either AbsolutePath or RelativePath. With the absolute path you need not use ID to identify the element which is created dynamically. The path is identified using the location of the elements within the tags.

Example for Absolute Path: 
`//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/input[3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("classname"));    

for(WebElement ele : elements) {
    System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='View seats']")).get(index).click()
```

You can try this method.But i'm not sure it can work out.I'm looking for a general way which can solve the problem at dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here when the dynamic-Data Table  is coming so you can store the size of  in the table, Like :

```
 int size = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='demo_ID']/tbody/tr")).size();
```

And can set a loop which would read every available row of the table or you can click on them one by one. Like :

```
String strGetContent = text.getText();
or
text.click(); // As per your need
```

Now you can read or click every row of the table, although rows are coming dynamically.I hope it helped you!

For more explanation or an example I would prefer: [How to Automate a Dynamic page through Selenium Web Driver](http://asktofolks.com/305/how-to-automate-a-dynamic-page-through-selenium-web-driver)